# Center inline image to fit browser like image with its own url would (and with 100% width or height and no stretching)

Tags: javascript, resize, center

I have a webcam with vertical-align: middle; here: http://flamencopeko.net/cam.php. Works. But I want the scroll-bars to never appear. The fact that the image updates has no importance to what I'm trying to make. I'm thinking something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (x==1)
  {
  document.write
  ("<img src='webcam.jpg' name='webcam' style='width: 100%; height: auto' alt='webcam' hspace='0' vspace='0' />");
  }
  else
  {
  document.write
  ("<img src='webcam.jpg' name='webcam' style='width: auto; height: 100%' alt='webcam' hspace='0' vspace='0' />");
  }
</script>
```

Here's the complete code for the test version: http://flamencopeko.net/cam3.txt

Will not show 100% height when I change the variable in head from 1 to anything else.

I plan to read the inner html x and y values and then make the image adjust to that.

Comment: instead of doing 100%, try giving width and height like 400. The pic captured from your webcam is large and 100% follows pic's size. Make the picture smaller

Comment: Full size is the whole point of this. Small size is on site's main page. Clicking it brings user to full size version. Click again brings user back to main page. The picture is only 640 x 480, as the Sphere cam I use is old.

Comment: In fact any way to make image height 100% and width auto would be very helpful.